# Unable to open a url in chrome and sfari

Tags: javascript

```
I am using openModal() javascript function ,its working fine in ie ,but in chrome and safari its appending base url with url i am sending,resulting in an error? Please Help!!

    function OpenModalReplyDialog(url, SubscriberId) {
        //Todo: Cleanup the unnecessary code.
        var returnValue = new ModalReturnValue(null, null, null);
        var retVal = null;
        var urlredirect = url + '/UC_5_0_0.aspx?SubscriberId=' + SubscriberId;

        returnValue = openModal(urlredirect, 350, 500);

        return true;
    }
```

This is code for openModal()
    function openModal(url, width, height, args, options)
    {
        var returnValue = new ModalReturnValue(null, null, null);
        var dialogArguments = self;
        var defaultWindowOptions = 'center:yes;status:no;unadorned:yes;help:no;resizable:yes;';

```
    if(args !=null)
    {
        dialogArguments = args;
    }

    var windowOptions = 'dialogHeight:' + height + 'px;dialogWidth:' + width + 'px;' + (options != null ? options : defaultWindowOptions);

    returnValue = window.showModalDialog(url, dialogArguments, windowOptions);

    if (returnValue != null)
    {
        if (returnValue.Command == "TimeOut") {
            if (pageSessionTimeoutInfo != null) {
                if (pageSessionTimeoutInfo.IsModal) {
                    closeModal(returnValue);
                    return;
                }
            }
            redirectToUrl(returnValue.Url);
        }
        else
            return returnValue;            
    }
    else
        return returnValue;    
}
```

Comment: openModal() is undefined in your code sample, are you using window.showModalDialog()?

Comment: yes i am using window.showModalDialog() in open Modal()

Answer (score 0):

window.showModalDialog() is deprecated, it’s removed by Chrome & Firefox etc but works in IE. Please consider other options like Jquery dialog or bootstrap dialog or HTML5 dialog element. window.showModalDialog polyfill using a dialog element, click [here](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog) for details.

Comment: No, it doesn't : http://forums.asp.net/t/1626197.aspx?window+showModalDialog+is+not+working+in+safari+on+Mac+os